# How to detect App Install on iOS from affiliate link?

Tags: ios, ads

Is there a way to track if the App is installed from our affiliate link without using apple linkshare or anything?

One way to do so was save the time the link was clicked and then use `UIApplication openURL` to check if we are able to open the app after a while. If we can open, that means the app was installed from our link.

Is there any other reliable way to detect it?

How does Facebook App Ads detect if the app was installed from their link?

Thanks.

Comment: You have the provider token which lets you track campaigns in iTunesConnect's App Analytics, although it sounds like you want the device to know.